# Invalid operation. The Connection is closed error when using Petapoco FetchAsync

Tags: petapoco

I am using the petapoco.compiled v6.0.441 in my MVC project. This is working fine for all the synchronous operations. But when I try to use the FetchAsync<> it is throwing an error 'Invalid Operation. The Connection is closed'.

```
//controller
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
     IEnumerable<UserEntity> users= await userService.GetAllAsync();
     return View(users);
}

//user service
public Task<List<UserEntity>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return userrepository.GetAllAsync();
}

//user repo - trial 1
public Task<List<UserEntity>> GetAllAsync()
{
    var res = db.FetchAsync<UserEntity>("select query");

    return res;
}

also tried
//user repo - trial 2
public async Task<List<UserEntity>> GetAllAsync()
{
    var res = await db.FetchAsync<UserEntity>("select query");

    return res;
}
```

Not sure whether the above implementation is correct or I missed something, Do I have to configure petapoco to support Async?

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 1):

I see this regularly, it's most likely you're leaking the `db` instance to multiple threads.

Steps to test and confirm. Isolate the web/api and issue a single request. If single requests work, the issue is as described.